# Can't Sign Signature: error: Task failed with exit 1 signal 0 {

Tags: xcode, swift4, xcode9

Getting error "Can't verify/Sign Signature: error: Task failed with exit 1 signal 0 {"

Xcode9.1
iOS 11.1
iPhone 6

I've googled and seen lot of this error asked, but none of the solutions work in my case (delete Derived Data & clean build folder).

When I try to make a build to my iPhone, I get this error (signed in on correct AppleID and so on). Build in simulator works fine. It did work by creating a new AppleID, and then verify it in 'profiles & device management', but I can't jump between the new AppleID and my main one.

Sorry if I got some expressions wrong, started with Xcode today. Thanks!

[image: Printscreen of error]

Comment: Please past the error into the text of your question.  Also, consider formatting your errors.

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue that I ran into while trying to build an app and simulating it on my phone.

Solution : When prompted to enter your password in keychain, press the 'always allow', not simply allow.

If you are currently in this process, restart your computer, then open Xcode, and simulate on a Generic device, then you should get prompted to re-enter your password again. Make sure to click always allow.

(if this didn't work, then make sure that all your sign in certificates are good to go and updated).

If that still doesn't work, try to upload the app to the iTunes Connect to testflight the app.

Hope this works. :)

Comment: Restarting my computer alone did it for me.